# What do you call a person who gets hungry easily?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is there a word to describe a person who gets hungry easily? If there is, are there any antonyms for it?

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone with a ***fast metabolism*** generally gets hungry more easily, as s/he burns up consumed calories more quickly than does someone with a ***slow metabolism***.

You could describe someone who eats small amounts frequently as a *grazer* or a *snacker*.

(See also: Teenager.)

Comment: +1, though I've heard *[high metabolism](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=high+metabolism%2Cfast+metabolism&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)* far more often.

Comment: Marked as answer. I think it is quite hard to have a single word as mention by Robert Cartaino but I still OK with the word `fast metabolism`.

Answer (score 3):

Merriam Webster defines [ravenous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ravenous) as 'being very greedy or eager for food.' Also, *gluttonous* refers to a person who overeats.

*Gourmand* is sometimes used as a synonym for 'glutton.'

*Bulimia* refers to an eating disorder characterized by consuming large amounts of food. [This links](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bulimic) to an explanation of *bulimic*.

Comment: In modern usage, `bulimia` tends to refer to a disorder in which a person binges and purges, rather than just binging.

Comment: :-) didn't know about the *purging*- thankfully, I'm not bulimic, and nobody I know is, either- but thanks for sharing!

Comment: +1 Never thought that can use the word `ravenous` to describe a person who is hungry easily.