# Is there a word for 'a person who is always hungry'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say I'm always hungry, even after I have my meal(s). What would be a word to express that? IMHO, I think **starving**, **famished** won't be applicable as these words would only describe the current situation.

Comment: Your stomach is like a bottomless pit.

Comment: You're happy with an adjective, right? Because otherwise you should specify you want a noun.

Comment: If you were In India, you'd be called "Kumbhkarna". He's a mythological devil from the epic "Ramayana" who eats for 6 months and sleeps for the remaining 6!

Comment: Closely related, some answers there fit your context well - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49558/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-gets-hungry-easily

Comment: I had a young colleague who had "a metabolism like a nuclear reactor."   However much he ate, he remained lean.  As he grew older, his metabolism slowed down to normal.  Fortunately, he adjusted his food intake and remained lean.  (Don't think of yourself as a glutton, as one answer suggested.)

Comment: @BiscuitBoy I'm glad my friends don't know about this devil ;)

Comment: *insatiable* means "cannot be satisfied". *voracious* means "having an (unusual) capacity or desire to eat"

Comment: Cartoon aficionados of a certain age will recognize the term _Wimpie_ as being synonymous with a person who eats constantly and yet is always happy to eat more. However, the term _wimp_ has made _Wimpie_ in the "voracious eater" sense virtually unusable without an attendant explanation.

Comment: You might call such a person a ["wendigo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendigo#Description).

Comment: Always hungry even immediately after eating meals? *Ill* or *sick*.

Comment: A college student

Comment: A normal teenager

Comment: Please tell me why "fat" isn't the answer.

Comment: I typed the Dutch word for someone who's always hungry into Google Translate, and it returned "starveling". Never heard of that word though.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Consider ***insatiable [appetite]***.

*Insatiable* means:

> always wanting more : not able to be satisfied ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insatiable))
>
> Impossible to satiate or satisfy: *an insatiable appetite* ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/insatiable))

For example,

> Most children like to eat but for some an insatiable appetite means they always want more, causing real problems for parents. ([BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-23404682))
>
> The woman is insatiable.  When the final whistle blows, she's eaten twenty-three sandwiches in ten minutes, setting a world record ([*Eat this Book*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SP3CK4iGDK4C&pg=PA52))
>
> [Children] may go through phases where they seem to eat relatively little or are insatiable. ([*Feeding the Under 5s*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8IwHQ3sSGOoC&pg=PA6))

Comment: But would you ever call a person themselves insatiable, or only their appetite. I think you probably could, but an example to quote would really make the case!

Comment: @curiousdannii - calling a person insatiable is ambiguous if you don't specify which particular appetite. Certainly in British English it  could well be taken to mean having (for example) an insatiable sexual appetite.

Comment: @curiousdannii I've added a couple examples demonstrating that *insatiable* can be used on its own.  Still, context is crucial: without a nearby reference to eating, the term by itself is indeed ambiguous.

Answer (score 17):

There are lots of other answers here already, but none seems to have brought up the colorful folk idiom ***hollow leg.***

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hollow_leg) glosses with some quotations, of which I here reproduce the first, which sufficiently illustrates how the expression is used (so-and-so *has a hollow leg):*

> Capacity to eat large quantities
>
> - 1998, Barbara Kingsolver, *The Bean Trees,* page 228: When I was young and growing a lot, and Mama couldn't feed me enough, she used to say I had a hollow leg.

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hollow%20leg) glosses:

> Imaginary reservoir for one who overindulges in liquor, food, etc. without showing signs of effect.

Comment: In en-gb, normally plural: "hollow legs".

Comment: I've never heard that used for food - I've only heard of it used specifically for liquor, i.e. a person who doesn't get drunk.

Answer (score 12):

"Voracious" derives from the Latin for devour (which also gives words like carnivore and omnivore).

[Voracious: having or showing a tendency to eat very large amounts of food](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/voracious)

(To me this seems like one of the less judgment-laden word choices.)

Comment: Voraciousness doesn't imply that one would continue to be hungry after eating a lot, though, so I don't think this quite applies.

Answer (score 10):

I think  ***[glutton](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/glutton)*** comes close to what you are referring to:

> - a person who eats and drinks excessively or voraciously.

(Dictionary.com)

> - a person who eats or consumes immoderate amounts of food and drink.

(AHD)

Comment: This word has a strong negative connotation. Certain people (e.g. teenage boys, professional athletes) simply can't get enough calories without a lot of effort.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - OP is not very specific about the context, I think it is a term that fits the the general context of "a person who is always hungry". There are not only teen agers and athletes around, but unluckily also people who can't control their appetite for whatever reason.

Comment: I agree, I just prefer `insatiable` for its neutrality. Your answer is certainly not incorrect.

Comment: A glutton is not always hungry. A glutton just likes to eat a lot. That is not what the question asked.

Comment: @Floris - just likes to eat a lot? ...so you mean a glutton is usually very hungry.

Comment: No - you don't have to be hungry to eat; it is sufficient to be greedy. And I think a glutton can be satisfied. "Glutton" refers to the (enjoyment of) eating, not to hunger; "insatiable" refers to the state of being hungry (not full, not satisfied). I think the latter is definitely the better word.

Comment: @Floris - Whatever the reason (and I don't think that gluttonery refers to the enjoyment of eating  - if you have reference on that please provide it) it represents an instance of being always hungry ( what OP is asking).

Comment: A glutton doesn't necessarily enjoy eating, and a glutton isn't necessarily hungry all the time. A glutton just eats (and/or drinks) a lot.

Comment: Just be advised, it's probably not very PC to call e.g. a person suffering from hyperorexia a glutton.

Comment: @JasonC - why are you supposing that I might do that?  I am aware of the term meaning and usage,

Comment: @Josh61 I am not. I am supposing that ~3006 other people who are not you have read this, and that more who are also not you will continue to do so in the future.

Comment: @JasonC - I really dont understand why this term has attracted so much criticism, while other suggestions, probably "as inappropriate as mine" have not.

Comment: @Josh61 I was not criticizing. However, as a suggestion, if you add a note about its connotation to your answer you might mitigate some of the comments, since the other answers here do seem to contain at least some mention of typical usage and yours does not (hence the comments attempting to add missing info).

Comment: @JasonC - well, maybe. But as a matter of fact the "criticism" has been  directed toward "gutton" and not other (possibly inappropriate) terms. Probably the  term evokes something in those who read it.

Comment: I would argue that someone who is always hungry is *not* a glutton - that a glutton is *specifically* someone who frequently eats to excess, where excess is defined as "not still hungry".

Answer (score 8):

The phrase **bottomless pit** is sometimes used, although the context would have to be already set for it to make sense.

Answer (score 7):

In some parts of the UK, the term *gannet* is used, a reference to the North Atlantic bird known for supposedly eating large quantities of fish.

Comment: I love this word and use it whenever possible.

Answer (score 6):

Looking through this list of excellent answers, I don't see ***ravenous***, which our friends at Dictionary.com define as

> extremely hungry; famished; voracious:
>   *feeling ravenous after a hard day's work.*

If I want to sound particularly erudite, I might try ***esurient***, which is a Latinate word for pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Neither of these seem to indicate that the person so described would remain hungry after eating, though.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for something classy, you might try ***gourmand***, which is less insulting than some of the other options.  The closest translation would be simply a "lover of food", which doesn't necessarily mean constant hunger, but usually that is implied.  A gourmand probably has more expensive tastes than a mere glutton, however.

Comment: Gourmand is one who likes large quantities of food, "chowhound" in military slang. Gourmet is one who likes the best quality of food, not implying gluttony.

Comment: @Theresa - Well, no.  "Gourmet" refers to the person who makes the food, not the person who eats it.  The chef is a gourmet, not the diner.  (At least by the original meaning of these words in French, though definitions sometimes shift over time.)

Comment: my comment was a paraphrase of both the Merriam Webster and the Oxford dictionaries. Both sources had a definition which used the word "palate", i.e. roof of the mouth. I know French, too, but this is an English forum.

Answer (score 3):

I would call him/her [**foodaholic**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/foodaholic) which means:

> a person having an excessive, often uncontrollable craving for food.

[Dictionary.com]

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a completely over-the-top historical allusion, you might say that you're *a regular [Tarrare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarrare)*. Tarrare was a French soldier of the 18th century who suffered from *polyphagia*:

> He was granted quadruple rations but remained hungry; he would scavenge for garbage in gutters and refuse containers, eat the scraps of food left by other patients, and creep into the apothecary's room to eat the poultices. Military surgeons could not understand his appetite.

If the story of Tarrare is too vivid for your use-case, *insatiable* would probably be about right.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context, consider:

***bulimic***

> **bulimia**
>
> A raging hunger or voracious appetite. [Food & Nutrition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Food+and+Nutrition)
>
> Also called [**hyperphagia**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphagia). *Pathology.* abnormally voracious appetite or unnaturally constant hunger. [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bulimia?s=t)
>
> An abnormal and constant craving for food [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bulimia)

***hyperorexic***

> hyperorexia: an abnormal craving for food; a voracious and insatiable appetite. [Ologies & -Isms](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hyperorexia)

Comment: It's worth noting that one needs to be extremely careful with *bulimic*; in most (but perhaps not all) contexts, this will be understood to mean that the hungry person has an eating disorder.

Comment: On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulimia_nervosa) it says *Bulimia is an eating disorder characterized by binge eating followed by purging.* So, as @Nathaniel mentioned, it sounds more like *an eating disorder*.

Comment: @Nathaniel Someone who is always hungry actually might have an eating disorder.

Comment: Sure, that's definitely possible.  All I'm saying is that it's crucial to recognize that dominant usage when using this term.

Comment: @Nathaniel Fair point. I just edited my answer.

Comment: Hyperphagia is an excellent find, by the way. See [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphagia).